# Display long text using django template variable

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I am trying to pass a text of 555000 characters into my Django template ( from view method )  accessible by a template variable.

The text does not get rendered in the template.

```
        params["content"] = my_file.read()
        my_file.close()
```

However, It gets rendered if the characters are truncated to approx 250,000 characters.

```
params["content"] = params["content"][0:252066]
```

Template:

```
  {{content|linebreaks }}
```

What should be my workaround to show full text?

Comment: I don't know of a limitation that would cause this, but there might be one. Have you tried just seeing if this is a lazy-evaluation thing? Does params['content'] = params['content'][:] work? (i.e. if you evaluate the whole list)

Comment: I just tried this on my system with a 555000 char long file, and it does render the full content(plus extra space chars to the end) - I suspect the file contents might have some problem with the Django template escaping mechanism(my file was just repeated 'a's).

Comment: Is there a specific escaping mechanism you suggest me to have @yatisagade

Comment: I have no idea :| Does your file contain HTML special characters?

Comment: I tried turning on/off autoescape. No avail. No, plain text as of now.